# How to ask the user to sign multiple transactions at once using anchor?

Tags: anchor, javascript

I succeeded to have 2 transactions being executed one after the other. I am trying to only ask the user to validate the transaction on wallet once using `signAlltransactions`.

1. Works with 2 transactions:

```
const txInitializeArticle = await program.methods
    .initializeArticle(
        uuid,
        newArticleFormData.country,
        newArticleFormData.category)
    .accounts(
        {
            user: publicKey,
            article: article,
            sellerAccount: sellerAccount,
            store: storePubKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programID,
        })
    .rpc()

await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(txInitializeArticle, "confirmed")
console.log(txInitializeArticle)

const price = new BN(parseFloat(newArticleFormData.price) * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
const txPostArticle = await program.methods
    .postArticle(
        price,
        newArticleFormData.quantity,
        newArticleFormData.title,
        newArticleFormData.description,
        newArticleFormData.imageURL)
    .accounts(
        {
            user: publicKey,
            article: article
        })
    .rpc()
```

how to transform this to one transaction with `signAllTransactions` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.instruction` rather than `.rpc`

```
const tx = new Transaction();
const ixInitializeArticle = await program.methods
    .initializeArticle(
        uuid,
        newArticleFormData.country,
        newArticleFormData.category)
    .accounts(
        {
            user: publicKey,
            article: article,
            sellerAccount: sellerAccount,
            store: storePubKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programID,
        })
    .instruction()
const ixPostArticle = await program.methods
    .postArticle(
        price,
        newArticleFormData.quantity,
        newArticleFormData.title,
        newArticleFormData.description,
        newArticleFormData.imageURL)
    .accounts(
        {
            user: publicKey,
            article: article
        })
    .instruction()

tx.add(ixInitializeArticle).add(ixPostArticle);
```

You can then pass tx into `signAllTransactions`